# How to write a Maven POM file for play framework project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, playframework, playframework-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good way to mavenify a play! framework application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366904/is-there-a-good-way-to-mavenify-a-play-framework-application)

I just starting playing with play framework for my new project. I am not familiar with scala and no idea about sbt build and deployment tool. I am using java to write my application with play framework.

I read this in the play [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SBTDependencies)

" It’s also possible to write a Maven POM file or Ivy configuration file to externally configure your dependencies, and have sbt use those external configuration files."

I need to build and store my application in my local nexus repository. But I was not able to find how to generate a default POM for my applicatilon and use it to manage dependencies and deploy it after building to my local nexus repository.

Answer (score 0):

Just for prosperity, have a look at the answers here: [Is there a good way to mavenify a play! framework application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366904/is-there-a-good-way-to-mavenify-a-play-framework-application)